# Java Print XML to console

Tags: java, xml

I have this code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;



public class Main {

    private static Document loadTestDocument(String url) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(url).openStream());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document  doc = loadTestDocument("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("note").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

and as as far as I'm concerned this should print node text to java console, but it seems to print nothing... There's no error or anything.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero item is **note**. It has no value.Use above code to print Tove

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("note").item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
```

Comment: Why is the answer always so simple? :) Thank you loljeene

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to get text content

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("note").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent()
```

**EDIT**
Try this, there are some empty nodes.

```
int i;
 for(i = 0; i < doc.getElementsByTagName("note").item(0).getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
     System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("note").item(0).getChildNodes().item(i).getTextContent());
 }
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep. The result with 'getTextContent()' is exactly the same.

Comment: @Pawel I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  Document  doc = loadTestDocument("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  Element element =(Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("note").item(0);

  System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0).getTextContent());
  System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("from").item(0).getTextContent());
```

**Output:**

Tove

Jani

Answer (score 1):

With another api Jsoup, we can parse the xml and print entire xml as string on console

Try this out with below snippet:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"), 5000);
        System.out.println("XML content : "+document.html());
```

Output:

```
<note> 
 <to>
  Tove
 </to> 
 <from>
  Jani
 </from> 
 <heading>
  Reminder
 </heading> 
 <body>
  Don't forget me this weekend!
 </body> 
</note>
```